# How to register a user device for chat push via API call? Only see documentation on CLI

Tags: getstream-io

I need to register a user's device to get chat push notifications. The docs only show how to do it using the CLI (`stream chat:push:device:add`) but I need to it via API or client. Is there an API endpoint to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `/devices` endpoint (`GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`) is used for managing devices. Currently there's SDK examples available for NodeJS, Python and Ruby here https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#push_devices.